# Ubuntu 14.04 Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0) can't connect

Tags: networking, router, wired

Why can't I connect to my router via simple LAN cable? I just want to access my router and configure it, but my Ubuntu keeps attempting to make a wired connection and it can't.
I tried switching my Wi-Fi off, tried different cables, and still I can't make a wired connection to my router.
Please help!

Comment: Please give output of "lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2"

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the correct command? I get "command not found"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Here is the output: lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1851]
 Kernel driver in use: atl1c

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You probably omitted spaces somewhere. Do not type it, but copy and paste. E.g. there is a space after lspci.

Comment: And which kernel do you use? Give output of "uname -r".

Comment: "uname -r"
3.13.0-52-generic

Answer (score 2):

There were some issues with this network adapter Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0) in older kernels. I suggest that you upgrade kernel to 3.16. It can be done by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

This kernel is default in 14.04.2.

But you need to connect to the Internet using wifi, if it works.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This worked :) I owe you a beer :D

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!